How to integrate $ \int e^{\sin x} \cos(2x) \, dx $?
I'm trying to evaluate the integral:
$
\int e^{\sin x} \cos(2x) \, dx
$
I've tried using trigonometric identities to simplify $ \cos(2x) $ into $ 2\cos^2(x) - 1 $, but it didn't seem to make the integral easier. I also considered other substitutions like: $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$, but nothing has worked so far. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this integral?
Could it be a textbook typo?
Textbook Problem Image (Method should be integration by parts)

Hello Jaisel and welcome to mate SE. Can you please tell what is the source of this problem? This will simply have no elementary anti-derivative

Integral-calculator says that $\int e^{\sin x}\cos(2x)dx$ does not have an elementary antiderivative. So it is likely a typo.

If it's integration by parts maybe it was supposed to be $e^x\cos(2x)$

or $e^{\sin(x)}\cos(x)$

I would guess that it was meant to be $\sin(2x)$ instead of $\cos(2x)$, which does admit a simple solution by parts.

Wait, the textbook literally says $\mbox{sen } x$, not $\sin x$.  Does the book define what $\mbox{sen}$ means?  Update: according to Google, $\mbox{sen}$ is sometimes used instead of $\sin$ in some languages.

@madhurkant  The problem is from a homework assignment given by my teacher, link is here. The specific problem I'm referring to is on the last page.

@ErickWong That’s what I was thinking as well. Or also: $ \sin(x) $ and $ \cos(x) $

@ErickWong sen(x) refers to sin(x) but in Spanish.

@Jasiel It's a typo. I can't figure out how to solve it using integration by part. Many function has no anti derivative

Thank you all for your inputs. I’m now convinced that it’s most likely a typo, as I suspected.

@madhurkant Yes, that's what I thought, but I wanted to get a second opinion, thanks!

It is a typo and then (+1) for having tried.

$\int \exp^{\sin x} \sin(2x),dx$ does have an elementary antiderivative using integration by parts.  I suspect this is what the author intended but got the double-angle formula mixed up.

If you want to tease your teacher, tell that the result is $$\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\sin^n(x),\cos(2x)} {n!},dx$$
